# Conditional Array Merge in Swift

Tags: swift

*Using SwiftUI 3.0 and Swift 5.5 on Xcode 13.2, target development > iOS* 15.0.0

I'm trying to merge two arrays if a condition is met, but only one if it isn't.

I have come up with this simple function:

```
func conditionalArrayMerge(primaryArray: [Item], secondaryArray: [Item], condition: Bool) -> [Item] {
        if condition {
            return primaryArray + secondaryArray
        } else {
            return primaryArray
        }
    }
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

I *don't* want to do it like this

```
return condition ? primaryArray + secondaryArray : primaryArray
```

I tried doing it like so:

```
return primaryArray + { condition ? secondaryArray : [] } as [Item]
```

But obviously, it didn't work (unless it's not obvious?)

What's the most efficient way to return an array with conditional merges?

Thank you!

Comment: "I don't want to do it like this" <- what's wrong with that way of doing it?

Comment: Because I want to see if there's an even shorter method to get the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you need parentheses around your ternary expression, not `{}`.

```
return primaryArray + (condition ? secondaryArray : [])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a variant of `reduce` that is missing from the standard library.

```swift
condition.reduce(primaryArray) { $0 + secondaryArray }
```

```swift
public extension Bool {
  /// Modify a value if `true`.
  /// - Returns: An unmodified value, when false.
  @inlinable func reduce<Result>(
    _ resultWhenFalse: Result,
    _ makeResult: (_ resultWhenFalse: Result) throws -> Result
  ) rethrows -> Result {
    self
      ? try makeResult(resultWhenFalse)
      : resultWhenFalse
  }
}
```